# get all child elements on Appium 1.2

Tags: selenium, xpath, automated-tests, ui-automation, appium

i'm trying to update Appium version from 0.16 to 1.2 (ios, Java)
on the old version i'm using webElement.findElements(By.xpath("*")) to get all webElement's child elements. this syntax doesn't work on 1.2 version.

any ideas how can i get all child elements?

Thanks,

Idan

Comment: were you able to find solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to consider CSS selector alternative as CSS working faster than xPath.
So the common rule is following:

- B as a descendant of A : children, grandchildren etc.

  ```
    A B
  ```
- B as a child of A

  ```
   A > B
  ```
- all elements

  ```
   *
  ```

  So select **all child elements from all elements on the page**:

  ```
   * > *
  ```

So in java it be:

```
List<WebElement> a = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("* > *"));
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: can you show an example for the syntax on Java? i don't know how to use the css selectors

Comment: Appium doesn't support CSS selectors. Or am I missing something?

Comment: yes, the example will give you error " Invalid locator strategy"